# Meaning of "pdftex supports JPEG EXIF"

Tags: pdftex, texlive

According to this https://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html of TeXLive 2015:

> pdftex (full pdfTeX news)
>       Support JPEG Exif as well as JFIF; do not even emit a warning if \pdfinclusionerrorlevel is negative; sync with xpdf-3.04

To my understanding Exif is a format or a standard for the metadata of an image.

**How is `pdftex` going to use that EXIF metadata?**

Will the metadata be kept in the PDF somewhere? (where?)

How can this be useful in practice? (or is this something else completely?)

Comment: It is a change to `writejpg.c`, apparently, borrowed from `dvipdfm-x` (https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/pdftexdir/ChangeLog?revision=36291&view=markup). [I'm none the wiser but perhaps you will be?]

Comment: The ChangeLog may well be not strictly correct, since
I'm not familiar with the file format of jpeg images.
There are jpeg images, for example ones created by
Adobe Photoshop, where the offset 06 to 09 is
`Exif` instead of `JFIF`. It says simply that the
new pdfTeX supports also such jpeg images.